# hide nav bar dont hide when scrolling and i want it toggle when i scroll by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, uinavigationbar

I have typed every thing right but does not work.

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function () {
  var currentScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollpos) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("nav").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("nav").style.top = "-100px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollpos;
};
```

Comment: as we see your code it is obviously doing something, but on something completely unknown ...  please read :https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try again this code. Should be `document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0]`

```
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function () {
      var currentScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollpos) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].style.top = "0";
      } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].style.top = "-100px";
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollpos;
    };
```